# DAML: I am prompted to login to Bintray Edit Profile even after SAML Slgn In

Tags: daml

After signing into Bintray via SAML authentication, when I click on the link or go to the following URL: https://bintray.com/login?targetUri=/profile/edit I am prompted to sign in again. I am trying to get the Bintray username and API key so that I can configure Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the API key using my windows device instead,